# Dash bar is not comming up 12.04

Tags: nvidia, unity-dash, gui, autohide

I have an nVidia card and drivers installed.
Everything was going on correctly until I installed he updates.
After the updates(nVidia drivers are also updated) the hidden Dash bar stays hidden :(
Is it a bug? Does it have any fixes?
I am thinking to reinstall Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried hitting the windows button on your keyboard ?

Comment: Yes it works but it doesn't come up using mouse... :(
Need of pressing super key for menu is annoying!

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  NVidia driver version 304.51

Comment: Yes yes the same here... nVidia driver version 304.51!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved !!!

Updated the nVidia driver to version 304.60.

I think it has the fix for the bug in version 304.51.

Now the dash bar works fine. :D